# sprite tapped on in xna

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, xna-4.0

how to get the sprite tapped in xna for WP7 ? how to detect which sprite is tapped on? I want to get the sprite id or anything which give me the reference of that particular sprite which i tapped on.

Answer (score 1):

There's no out-of-the-box way to do that using XNA. You'll have to get the tap coordinates, then manually check if there's a sprite in those coordinates.